# 'TestTreeDict' object has no attribute 'test_common_dict'

Tags: python

I try to realise dictionary via binary tree. I try to make test for contains method, but there's error:"'TestTreeDict' object has no attribute 'test_common_dict'". Please, explain me, what do me do wrong?

```
from Tree import BinaryTree
from Tree import TreeNode
from DictBase import DictBase

class SimpleTreeDict(BinaryTree, DictBase):
    def __init__(self, *nodes):
        for node_tuple in nodes:
            self.add_node(TreeNode(node_tuple[0], node_tuple[1]))

    def contains(self, needed_key):
        return self.nodes_list.__contains__(needed_key)

#this is tests
import unittest
from Tree import BinaryTree
from Tree import TreeNode
from TreeDict import SimpleTreeDict


class TestTreeDict(unittest.TestCase):
    def set_Up(self):
        self.test_common_dict = SimpleTreeDict()
        self.test_common_dict = SimpleTreeDict(("ASUS", 80000),
            ("Toshiba", 65000), ("Dell", 90000), ("Acer", 75000),
            ("Apple", 100000), ("Samsung", 60000))
        self.test_little_dict = SimpleTreeDict(("ASUS", 80000), ("Toshiba", 
65000), ("Dell", 90000))
        self.test_empty_dict = SimpleTreeDict([])

    def test_contains(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.test_common_dict.contains("Toshiba"), True)
        self.assertEquals(self.test_little_dict.contains("Apple"), False)
```

Comment: Try replacing `def set_Up(self)` with `def setUp(self)`

Comment: Your code is not complete since Python does not have a `Tree` module in the standard library. Where did you get that module?

Comment: I rote this module myself, i thought, it woud be too large to insert it to this question)

Comment: @CFmoto6615 I'm voting to close your question, because it was caused by a mere typo.